# RedirectToAction with model and List properties

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a 2 views with model as Account. From view one, I am using RedirectToAction to go to view two and sending the model object as below:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(Account account)
    {
           //Some code here
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "AccountDetail", account);
    }
```

AccountDetail controller looks like this:

```
 public ActionResult Index(Account account)
    {
        return View("ViewNameHere", account);
    }
```

The model object contains a property like this:

```
 public class Account
 {
 // Some code here
 public List<Details> Details{
 get;
 set;
 }
```

In the first controller, before making call to `RedirectToAction` there is one item in Details. However, in the Index method of second controller, there is nothing.

Can someone help pointing out the flaw here? Since I am beginner with MVC, cannot seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not pass a complex object to a GET method. Apart from the ugly URL it would create, you could easily exceed the query string limit and throw an exception.

In any case you cannot pass a collection (or a complex object containing a collection) to a GET method using `RedirectToAction()`. Internally the method uses reflection to generate the query string by calling the `.ToString()` method of each property of the model, which in the case of your collection property will be something like `../AccountDetail/Index?Details=System.Collections.Generic.List<Details>`.

When the `Index()` method is called, a new instance of `Account` is initialized and the value of its property `Details` is attempted to be set to the string `System.Collections.Generic.List<Details>` which fails and the result is that property `Details` is `null`.

Options include passing an identifier and get the collection from the repository or `Session` or `TempData`

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot.